# How to have superscript in column header of this BootstrapVue table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrapvue table that looks like this;

[image]

Here's the code;

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
        fields: [
          {
            key: 'last_name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'first_name',
            sortable: false
          },
          {
            key: 'age',
            label: 'Person age',
            sortable: true,
            // Variant applies to the whole column, including the header and footer
            variant: 'danger'
          }
        ],
        items: [
          { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I want to change the 3rd column header `Person age` to have a superscript such that it becomes `Person age1`

Unfortunately, this is not as easy as using HTML inside the label for the 3rd column header.

I am using vue v2.6 and BootstrapVue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the markup (html) of a table header using the provided `#head({key})` [slot](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-slots):

```
<b-table>
  <template #head(age)="{ label }">
    {{ label }} <sup>1</sup>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

Obviously, you can place anything in there, including a filter search on that column, etc... It's all dynamic, connected to your component.

A few examples here: [Header and Footer custom rendering via scoped slots](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#header-and-footer-custom-rendering-via-scoped-slots).

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and most obvious solution for your narrow case: Use Unicode character U+00B9, SUPERSCRIPT ONE: ¹. In many cases this looks comparable to the HTML equivalent <sup>1</sup>, and will often appear more accurate when copied via the clipboard. Unicode offers [all  digits and several useful mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block), at least as many as you'll need for footnotes and endnotes.

Aside from that, Bootstrap Vue allows you to override particular cells with HTML via [table-specific scoped slots](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#header-and-footer-custom-rendering-via-scoped-slots), which are an application of Vue's general concept of [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) (also available in [Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html)). As in the Vue documentation, I"m using the [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-Shorthand) `#head(age)` instead of the [equivalent full attribute `v-slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-slot) as in `v-slot:head(age)`.

```html
<b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
  <template #head(age)>
    Person age<sup>1</sup>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

To avoid the duplication of "Person age" in both the field definition and custom slot, or to make better use of the general `head()` and `foot()` fallbacks to apply to all header and footer cells, you can specify an identifier that will take the slot context, which is defined to contain both `field` and `label`. Here I've used `context`, but you can name it whatever you'd like; you can also use [destructuring](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props), as in [tao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459269/1426891).

```html
<b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
  <template #head(age)="context">
    {{ context.label }}<sup>1</sup>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

The `fields` documentation notes that "Any additional properties added to the field definition objects will be left intact", so I imagine that if this case is common for you, you could even add a custom `field` object property (say, `note` or `superscript`) that you then render as `{{ context.label }}<sup v-if="context.field.note">{{ context.field.note }}</sup>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer my own question, thanks to the answer from @tao and the link he provided. It is a slight modification to his answer.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#header-and-footer-custom-rendering-via-scoped-slots

```
<b-table>
  <template #head(age)="data">
    {{ data.label }} <sup>1</sup>
  </template>
</b-table>
```