# How to fix this "Unexpected useless attribute on `<template>`" error in BootstrapVue table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

This question is a follow-up to the StackOverflow answer provided here

[How to have superscript in column header of this BootstrapVue table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71458966/how-to-have-superscript-in-column-header-of-this-bootstrapvue-table/71459269#71459269)

Here's the original code of the BootstrapVue table.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
        fields: [
          {
            key: 'last_name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'first_name',
            sortable: false
          },
          {
            key: 'age',
            label: 'Person age',
            sortable: true,
            // Variant applies to the whole column, including the header and footer
            variant: 'danger'
          }
        ],
        items: [
          { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here's the answer to add superscript to column header of BootstrapVue table.

```
<b-table>
  <template #head(age)="data">
    {{ data.label }} <sup>1</sup>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

The answer above works fine for the original code. However, the answer does not work if the original key name (`age`) has a space and % character in between (`%age new`). Here's the code when the name of the key has a space in between.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
        fields: [
          {
            key: 'last_name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'first_name',
            sortable: false
          },
          {
            key: '%age new', //space in between causes 
            label: 'Person age',
            sortable: true,
            // Variant applies to the whole column, including the header and footer
            variant: 'danger'
          }
        ],
        items: [
          { isActive: true, '%age new': 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { isActive: false, '%age new': 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { isActive: false, '%age new': 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { isActive: true, '%age new': 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

With this new space in between the key name, the corresponding answer becomes

```
<b-table>
  <template #head(%age new)="data">
    {{ data.label }} <sup>1</sup>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

I get the following error;

```
error  Unexpected useless attribute on `<template>`  vue/no-useless-template-attributes
error  Unexpected useless attribute on `<template>`  vue/no-useless-template-attributes
```

How to fix this error?

I am using vue v2.6 and BootstrapVue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue sees two attributes, `#head(%age` and `new)="data"`: They are parsed as HTML attributes first and foremost, and any syntactic meaning from Vue or Bootstrap-Vue (brackets and parens) comes later. The docs describe this behavior under "Dynamic Argument Syntax Constraints" ([v2 docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Argument-Expression-Constraints), [v3 docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#dynamic-argument-syntax-constraints)), which applies due to the complexity of the attribute name even though your property name isn't exactly dynamic:

> Dynamic argument expressions have some syntax constraints because certain characters, such as spaces and quotes, are invalid inside HTML attribute names. For example, the following is invalid:
>
> ```html
> <!-- This will trigger a compiler warning. -->
> <a v-bind:['foo' + bar]="value"> ... </a>
> ```
>
> The workaround is to either use expressions without spaces or quotes, or replace the complex expression with a computed property.

Though [attribute names are quite lenient](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/syntax.html#attribute-name) in the characters they accept, there's no way of escaping spaces, so you're stuck. This leaves you with two options:

- If you can define a computed property or data value `percentagePropertyName = "head(%age new)"` in your component, you could use that with the syntax `#[percentagePropertyName]` (etc).
- Change your field name to something without a special character, such as `percentage_new`. You can easily map this in your data objects, e.g. `dataArray = dataArray.map(x => ({ percentage_new: x["%age new"], ...x }));`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a string literals

```
<b-table>
  <template #head(`age new`)="data">
    {{ data.label }} <sup>1</sup>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

Or just replace the space with an underscore, or camelCase the key

Comment: Isn't `\n` new line?

Comment: @CristianTraìna You're right, thanks! Editing my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoted. What if the key is `%age new` with percentage sign in front? I tried your answer and it didn't work on my code. I wonder if it's to do with the percentage sign. I've modified the question to have the % sign.

Comment: @user3848207 I'm guessing that it can't parse the space, can you try wrapping the key inside with square brackets? like so `#head(['age new'])`. In case it doesn't work, my approach would be changing the key naming style, as it is not meant to be displayed anyways. The label key of every field is what's being displayed.

Comment: You could also try `#['head(age new)']`